# Block non-Android users calling JSON service

Tags: android, web-services, json, encryption

My Android application is calling a JSON service via HTTP and I would like to only allow my application to call the service and block others.

What is the best way to do it?

One way I can think of is using private/public key encryption. Can we embed a private key securely in the application?

Answer (score 2):

Include some hidden certificate/credentials in your app, different for each downloaded app. Then use these to authenticate. Even then this can *easily* be abused, nevertheless you have set up your first line of defense.

After that, try to set limits on the ratio in which a single client can request, throttle and blacklist as needed based on IP, credentials, etc.

Comment: "Include some hidden certificate/credentials in your app, different for each downloaded app." Would you mind elaborating on this? Do you have any example or links to illustrate how this can be done?

Comment: Well, what I meant was pretty general. The only reason for hiding them is that so they don't confuse the user. Think of a pretty standard username/password scheme with hashing, with the only different part being that the credentials are hidden, and are automatically sent to the server. This helps a bit to make the system a bit more non-trivial, and easier to track where the offensive may be coming from. If you want to improve on this a little more, you can add encryption and/or certificates, to be sent in the background. Your real interest is in tracking usage in as various as possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use HTTPS with authentication.

Edited:

The question here is not how to secure access to servers, but how to hide/secure credentials (passwords/certificates/etc..) on Android phones. The question should be: how to hide data inside Android apps.

One solution is to use an obfuscator like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This is not the easiest (which would be user-agent), and it is far from secured.

Comment: JSON services don't care about user-agent. User-agent are only useful when returning html to Browsers. Btw, you can still set user-agent with HttpClient.

Comment: HTTPS is secure - external parties can not snoop on it. And if it uses authentication with username/password than others can not connect to it.

Comment: But one can easily get the credentials by disassembling the app to its bits, and use them as easily.

Comment: Nothing prevents a JSON service from caring about the user-agent. Using a user/pwd will authenticate the user, not the application, or if you use it for the application, you are in the same case as a private-key solution.

Comment: You could (partially) fight against this with code obfuscation. For example http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator

Comment: The question here is about securing data inside Android apps not how to secure a server (we know solutions to this one).

Comment: As I understand it, the question is about restricting access to the server, not about securing data inside the app. The OP might need to clarify this ...

Comment: Guillaume is right. The question is about restricting other users to hit hard on our servers, not to allow them easily to find the way how the JSON service is called.

Comment: They can snoop the network to find where your app is connecting and then launch DoS on your IP. How do you prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you distribute your application, it can be disassembled. So a private key that would be distributed with your application could be extracted and reused.

There is no completly secured way of doing what you are trying to do. But there are ways to restrict clients, even if they are not foolproof.

The easiest (and least secured) would be to restrict access based on the user agent. But any client can fake the user agent.

A certificate / crypto solution is more robust, but as said above the certificate can be extracted from your app.

OAuth is used by some applications in the same context as yours. But OAuth was not designed for desktop (or mobile) apps and is also vulnerable to reverse engineering of the app.

You could authenticate the user (via a user / password, or other standard method). In this case, you dont restrict based on the plateform. Then, you can close the account of users abusing your service. This is a secured solution, but not exactly the answer to your problem.

Comment: Username/password over HTTPS is the only reasonably secure way today. This is what all biggest online services use (gmail, yahoo, etc..)